# Argument is missing, with no default

Tags: r, shiny

I have been unable to locate what is missing from the code posted below. I keep receiving the following error:

> "Error in tabsetPanel(id = "tracker", tabPanel("Premium",
>   tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css",  :    argument is missing,
>   with no default"

```
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "green",
  dashboardHeader(title="Niche Tool"),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
tags$style(HTML(".box-header{background:#d2d2d2; color:#d83000; text-align:center;}")),

shinyUI <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = 'tracker',
      tabPanel("Premium", 
               tags$head(tags$style( type = 'text/css',  '#myPivot{ overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: scroll; }')),
               rpivotTableOutput("pivot1", width = '100%', height = '300px'), br(), br(), br(), br(),br(), br(),
               rpivotTableOutput("pivot2", width = '100%', height = '300px')),
      #tabPanel("Incurred Losses"),
      tabPanel("Discretionary Pricing",
               rpivotTableOutput("pivot3", width = '100%', height = '300px'), br(), br(), br(), br(),br(), br(),
               rpivotTableOutput("pivot4", width = '100%', height = '300px')),

      )))))
```

Comment: Drop the comma after `rpivotTableOutput("pivot4", width = '100%', height = '300px'))`

Comment: Wow..... I guess it really is easy to overlook the simple things. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you like to save typing some `br()`s: `lapply(rep('', 6), br)` or use a css margin.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem as you and thanks to @ismirsehregal I could fix it.
Just in case someone wants to see a complete and "simple" example, here it is one which doesn't work.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("App"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        
        tabPanel("Tab1",
                 
        ),
        
        tabPanel("Tab2",
                 
        ),
        
        tabPanel("Tab3",
                 
        ),
        
        
        tabPanel("Tab4",
                 
        ),
        
      ),
      
      hr(),
      actionButton(inputId = "drawplot", label = "Show the plot")
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
      
    )
  ))
  
  
  library(shiny)
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$table <- renderTable({mtcars})
  }
  

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

I was getting this error:

```
Warning: Error in tabsetPanel: argument is missing, with no default
```

And the **solution** would be to delete the last comma from the last TabPanel.

```
tabPanel("Tab4",
                 
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "green",
                    dashboardHeader(title="Niche Tool"),
                    dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
                    dashboardBody(
                      tags$style(HTML(".box-header{background:#d2d2d2; color:#d83000; text-align:center;}")),

                      shinyUI <- fluidPage(
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(
                            tabPanel("Premium", 
                                     tags$head(tags$style( type = 'text/css',  '#myPivot{ overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: scroll; }')),
                                     rpivotTableOutput("pivot1", width = '100%', height = '300px'), br(), br(), br(), br(),br(), br(),
                                     rpivotTableOutput("pivot2", width = '100%', height = '300px')),
                            #tabPanel("Incurred Losses"),
                            tabPanel("Discretionary Pricing",
                                     rpivotTableOutput("pivot3", width = '100%', height = '300px'), br(), br(), br(), br(),br(), br(),
                                     rpivotTableOutput("pivot4", width = '100%', height = '300px')),id = 'tracker')))))
```

I cannot reproduce the example because I do not have the server part of the code but try this